# How to manually show/stop keyboard in UITextView textViewDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uialertcontroller

In `textViewDidBeginEditing` I'm doing some check to show `Alert`. My problem is that both Keyboard and Alert show up same time. I don't want keyboard to show when alert is shown. Is it possible to stop keyboard showing up inside `textViewDidBeginEditing` when I've to show Alert and once alert is dismissed revert it back to normal?

If not how do we achieve it via any other workaround?

Comment: is this question related to the previous one you have asked before ?

Answer (score 0):

Call  `view.endEditing(true)` function in `textViewDidBeginEditing` and keyboard didn't show. I think it's will work.

Comment: It does hide the keyboard but it scrolls up to show the space for keyboard as I've scroll view. So it's not the exact solution as scrolling up still occurs.

Comment: I do have this view.endEditing(true) being called after showing the alert async but it's again show and hide feature. Isn't there a way that we can totally stop showing keyboard and show it again manually?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the UITextView's isEditable property to false.
2. Detect for taps on the UITextView (that's what a user will do if he wants to start editing) possibly using a UITapGestureRecognizer and check if the tap coordinates lie within the frame of the UITextView.
3. At this time, the keyboard will not show. You can make the check you need, and based upon whether the check passes or fails, you can make the keyboard show (set UITextView's isEditbale to true and make it the firstResponder).
4. Once the user has finished editing, reset the state if you want to repeat the similar action.